# XML Serialization: How to distinguish classes that use the same element name but have a different value in an attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

The title may be long, let me explain what I mean. I won't give you the actual XML that I need to work with, but I'll give one that demonstrates the issue I'm facing.

I have an XML that looks like this:

```
<root>
    <creatures>
        <creature type="mammal" name="lion">
            <sound>roarr</sound>
        </creature>
        <creature type="bird" name="parrot">
            <color>red</color>
        </creature>
    </creatures>
</root>
```

Imagine the following classes:
(Of course these are not my real classes either, but you get the point.)

```
public class Creature
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MammalCreature : Creature
{
    public string Sound { get; set; }
}

public class BirdCreature : Creature
{
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to use XML Serialization with attributes in a manner that I want the serializer to distinguish between the types `MammalCreature` and `BirdCreature` by the `type` attribute.

I've found solutions that can do this by setting the `xsi:type` attribute to the type name I want, but I'd like to know if there is an actual solution that does this for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with just attributes, no.  However, this hairy looking code can indeed read your XML properly into a `Root` class:

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class Root : IXmlSerializable
{
    [XmlElement("creatures")]
    public Creatures Items { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is reserved and should not be used. When implementing
    /// the IXmlSerializable interface, you should return null (Nothing in
    /// Visual Basic) from this method, and instead, if specifying a custom
    /// schema is required, apply the
    /// <see cref="T:System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaProviderAttribute"/>
    /// to the class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// An <see cref="T:System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema"/> that describes the
    /// XML representation of the object that is produced by the
    /// <see cref="M:System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter)"/>
    /// method and consumed by the
    /// <see cref="M:System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader)"/>
    /// method.
    /// </returns>
    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates an object from its XML representation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="reader">The <see cref="T:System.Xml.XmlReader"/> stream
    /// from which the object is deserialized. </param>
    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.ReadStartElement("root");
        reader.ReadStartElement("creatures");

        List<Creature> creatures = new List<Creature>();

        while ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            && (reader.Name == "creature"))
        {
            Creature creature;
            string type = reader.GetAttribute("type");
            string name = reader.GetAttribute("name");

            reader.ReadStartElement("creature");

            switch (type)
            {
                case "mammal":
                    MammalCreature mammalCreature = new MammalCreature();

                    reader.ReadStartElement("sound");
                    mammalCreature.Sound = reader.ReadContentAsString();
                    reader.ReadEndElement();
                    creature = mammalCreature;
                    break;
                case "bird":
                    BirdCreature birdCreature = new BirdCreature();

                    reader.ReadStartElement("color");
                    birdCreature.Color = reader.ReadContentAsString();
                    reader.ReadEndElement();
                    creature = birdCreature;
                    break;
                default:
                    reader.Skip();
                    creature = new Creature();
                    break;
            }

            reader.ReadEndElement();
            creature.Name = name;
            creature.Type = type;
            creatures.Add(creature);
        }

        reader.ReadEndElement();
        this.Items = new Creatures();
        this.Items.Creature = creatures.ToArray();
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts an object into its XML representation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="writer">The <see cref="T:System.Xml.XmlWriter"/> stream
    /// to which the object is serialized. </param>
    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(Creatures)).Serialize(writer, this.Items);
    }
}

[XmlRoot("creatures")]
public class Creatures
{
    [XmlElement("creature")]
    public Creature[] Creature { get; set; }
}

[XmlInclude(typeof(MammalCreature))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(BirdCreature))]
public class Creature
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MammalCreature : Creature
{
    [XmlElement("sound")]
    public string Sound { get; set; }
}

public class BirdCreature : Creature
{
    [XmlElement("color")]
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer! Yeah, I thought that implementing IXmlSerializable would give me a solution, although I was looking for a KISS solution. Maybe I'll convince the person who created the schema to change it to a way supported by the attribute-based XML Serialization.

Comment: I know this is long after this answer was posted but I'm having some problems with this way of doing things.

Comment: @Hewins Then you should post a new question with what you've done and the exact problems you're encountering.

Answer (score 0):

Is it really critical for you to have the same Xml element name for the different types?

Your can end up being much more simple if you can live with the Xml looking like that:

```
<root>
    <creatures>
        <MammalCreature name="lion">
            <sound>roarr</sound>
        </MammalCreature>
        <Birdcreature name="parrot">
            <color>red</color>
        </BirdCreature>
    </creatures>
</root>
```

Comment: I agree, but obviously I'm not the one responsible for creating the XML schema.

Answer (score -2):

The XML Serializer does not support this scenario.